# SQL Server Install/Uninstall Freezes

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2019

I'm running Windows Server 2019 Standard. All Windows updates have been installed. Chckdsk, sfc, and dism have been run and found no problems. Server has been restarted.

I'm trying to uninstall some SQL Server 2014 instances and install a single SQL Server 2019 instance. Both processes freeze.

The SQL Server 2014 uninstall freezes after I select which features to uninstall and click next.

The SQL Server 2019 install freezes after I enter the instance name and click next.

I'm not sure what else to try or check. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i believe DBA or server fault may be better choices to ask this qiestion

Comment: have you checked event viewer?

Comment: Yes, I couldn’t find anything relevant.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/view-and-read-sql-server-setup-log-files?view=sql-server-ver16 The setup log files are a great place to start.

Comment: There is no Setup Bootstrap folder at the path that describes.

Comment: Do you have any restriction from antivirus or firewall ?

Comment: No. Running the same antivirus on another server that has no install issues. Firewall is the same as the other server too.